# Cookie undefined in service | cookie value exist in component | angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-cookie

api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';

import { CacheService  } from './cache.service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/core';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    constructor(
        public _http: Http, 
        private _auth: AuthService,
        private _cookie: CookieService,
        @Inject('isBrowser') public isBrowser: boolean
        ) {}

        get(){
          console.log(this._cookie.get('Token'));//undefined
        }
    }
```

controller.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { ReviewComponent } from '../shared/+review/review.component';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/core';
// import { ModelService } from '../shared/model/model.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'mall',
    templateUrl: './mall.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./mall.component.css'],
    providers: [ ApiService, CookieService ]
})
export class MallComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _api: ApiService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private _cookie: CookieService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this._cookie.get('Token');// Token => value
        this._api.get(); //Token => undefined
    }
}
```

I don't understand this behavior. The cookie exist when i access in controller directly but is undefined when i access through service.

Is there any way to access cookie through services?

using https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie with angular universal.

Comment: @Neel u even checked any of the link provided in the question? Please study the question first...understand the problem and make sure to reply with a reasonable statement.

Comment: Why doesn't `ApiService.get` return a value. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AluanHaddad i know that's why I asked the question. Otherwise there wasn't any need of this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake to add `CookieService` in component providers which initiate a new instance of service which was causing the issue.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'mall',
    templateUrl: './mall.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./mall.component.css'],
    providers: [ ApiService, CookieService ] //<--- here
})
```

*CookieService* should only be imported into **AppComponent(*root*)** to make a single instance available to other components.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
ngOnInit(){
  this._cookie.put('Token', WHATEVER_TOKEN_IS);// Token => value
  console.log(this._api.get('Token')); //Token => undefined
}
```

and then

**api-service**

```
export class ApiService {
  constructor(
    readonly _http: Http, 
    private _auth: AuthService,
    private _cookie: CookieService,
    @Inject('isBrowser') public isBrowser: boolean
    ) {}

    get() {
      const token = this._cookie.get('Token');
      console.log(token);
      return token;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what u have been smoking but the problem isn't about storing the cookie...the problem is why api call isn't returning the cookie with value while the component call is returning the value... Or is it supposed to be like this... If it is so..why ? and if it isn't then why there is irregularity...

Comment: Firstly, take it easy. Secondly, if you don't want answers like this you should refine your question so that the code makes at least vague sense. The code in your ngOnInit method doesn't make any sense.

Comment: and its understandable if a function is returning a value then value exist. I just simplified the code and provided with just the get code becoz the problem exist there. And your answer is just telling me to store value. Really what have u been smoking? If 2 function is being called 1 after the other..why would 1 of them wont return value. The order doesn't matter coz i tried calling the 2nd function 1st but the response is still same..function from service isn't returning value.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, but I went through the same problem.
I was not defining the base path as "/". So what was happening is that the cookie was being set for the default path where I was.
Eg. I was at site.com/auth/
Cookie would get saved at path "/auth"
If I save a cookie like

```
this.cookieService.set('token', token, null, "/");
```

then problem is solved.
Hope this helps further devs.

Comment: The issue was of providers. I have posted the answer